# GoCD Agent does not recognize JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, java-home, go-cd

I am testing Continuous Delivery Pipelines by using GoCD. The server and the agent live in separate Docker containers provided with Oracle Java 8.
I set up a test task which checks out my Git repository and uses maven for compiling. As a test command, I use a simple `mvn clean build`.

When I start the task I get the following failed build result:

`07:50:59.395 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project xxxxx: Compilation failure
07:50:59.395 [ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`

When I run the `mvn` command locally inside the container everything works fine. After long times searching for a solution I found hints concering problems with Java and Maven environment variables. 
On both systems, the output for those variables seems correct:

`go@d86b9572ed7e:/tmp$ echo $M2_HOME $JAVA_HOME
/usr/share/maven /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

The final solution I ended up with is setting the `$JAVA_HOME` variable as an environment variable in the GoCD server as a setting of the pipeline. Then, everything works fine, but I really don't understand why the system variables are not picked up by the agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent has a profile it uses to execute jobs and tasks. The default location is: /etc/default/go-agent
Add

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"
```

to this file.

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify environment variables in pipelines and stages.  If you use a common template for stages, you can define JAVA_HOME there.

Comment: Although it should, it does not work (Go Version: 16.6.0)